# Equals method throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, nullreferenceexception

I recently came about this problem. I have a base `Stamp` class. Then I made two inherited classes `OwnedStamp` and `AuctionStamp`. I overrided the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method in `Stamp` class like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj == null || this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Stamp stamp = obj as Stamp;
                return this.Title == stamp.Title;
            }
        }

public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Title.GetHashCode();
        }
```

I also have overloaded these operators in the same class:

```
public static bool operator ==(Stamp lhs, Stamp rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Equals(rhs);

        }
public static bool operator !=(Stamp lhs, Stamp rhs)
        {
            return !lhs.Equals(rhs);

        }
```

Then I have this scenario:

```
OwnedStamp checkStamp = check.GetStampByTitle(stampTitle);
if(checkStamp != null && checkStamp.Price <= toCompare.Price)
{
     picked.Add(check);
}
```

The `checkStamp` is not `null` and it holds the correct informtaion I need, but when i check for the equality for `null` it throws me the exception. I have other lines with code where I check for equality between two stamps of any type. I have tried couple of different Equals method realizations. The problem consists. I have red that checking equality in base class even if we pass child class to the method shouldn't be a problem. Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: the `Title.GetHashCode()` looks dangerous - can `Title` be `null` ? also: the `|| this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType())` means that if it is the **same** type, it'll never match... but isn't that when you *expect* it to match *the most*? btw, I think your `Equals` method should be just `return obj is Stamp stamp && stamp.Title == Title;`, and the `GetHashCode()` should probably be `return Title?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) Does this line `Stamp stamp = obj as Stamp;` work correct? Are you sure, that `stamp` isn't null here?

Comment: also, your equality operators are incredibly dangerous; if `lhs` is ever `null`: boom; you may also find it preferable to use `if (checkStamp is object && ...` in the check - this does a safe null check (not a type check, despite what it looks like)

Comment: This `this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType())` seems odd. You're saying it both types are the same then the instances cannot be equal.

Comment: The `checkStamp is object` helped with the `null` situation. It now works. I also changed the Equals method and it works with it too. That's a relief. Now I also would like to know about the `GetHashCode` situation. The `Title` cannot be null, because constructor has default values set, would still be a good idea to make `GetHashCode` perform a check?